# Override BizTalk FTPS Adapter Settings

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, ftps

When using the FTPS adapter to connect to an FTP site with SSL/TLS, I'm getting the following error:

> The server name in the server certificate does not match with the name of the physical server. Make sure you provide the right server name.  ".

Is there any way to override this behavior so that BizTalk will accept and use the certificate? I have the public certificate loaded into the personal store and the trusted store of the send handler user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I've come to the conclusion that this is a limitation of the Microsoft FTPS adapter. The only way to resolve this issue is to get certificates where the common name matches the DNS name, or to use a third-party FTPS adapter like the /n FTPS adapter.